# Android REST with Spring handle too long request

Tags: android, spring, rest

I am building a REST App with Spring. I am doing it the POJO way. Now I want to handle a GET Request that takes too long (lets say because the user has a very bad connection). What can I do to handle this (in Spring), maybe by canceling the request after 5000ms?

My approach:
So I guess there is a need for some kind of timeout. On my google-tour I found that there is a HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory and a so called setConnectTimeout() Function. I tested that but I can't handle the thrown Exception because its "to deep inside" and it gets passed out as a Fatal Exception of the AsyncTask. So I failed.

Whats the best practice? Any Idea?

**edit**:
Spring is set, so please only Spring solutions.

**edit**:
According to my research its not possible. Even @ Spring Forums is no answer yet: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135656-How-can-I-handle-GET-requests-that-are-taking-to-long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use an AsyncTask to perform network request because if you change the orientation of your device, Activity is destroyed and after recreated but the AsyncTask keep a reference on the destroyed Activity and cause some memory leaks.

Use Service instead. I suggest you to use [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). It's a library to easily make REST request with POJO and Spring.

If you're interesting in automatic local & remote data persistency management, you can use [RestDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid) to handle that (also with POJO).

Both library use RequestListeners to manage the case you're talking about. When your request failed, the UI is notify.

Answer (score 0):

Why not taking a simpler approach,
try this code and you'll get a more explicit exception:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: Nope, it's Android's client side.